# HashiCorp Vault SSO Authentication using Azure Active Directory & Terraform

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, single-sign-on, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault

I am looking to set up a HashiCorp Vault single sign-on authentication using Azure Active Directory (with OIDC) and provisioned through Terraform.

Now, I’ve come across a few useful examples online, but none so far has provided me with detailed, step-by-step guidance on how to achieve the following:

Set up and configure Azure Active Directory components including:

- App Registration
- Claims/Tokens
- Service Principals

Set up and configuration of Vault on my localhost.

Terraform code examples to enable me provision the required Azure resources to
achieve among others, the following:

- Configure OIDC
- Create an Azure Role, Groups, etc
- Read/Write secrets in Vault
- Successfully invoke and authenticate a login to Vault via OIDC

Anyone able to point me in the right direction, particularly towards any working examples with detailed, step-by-step scripts/code, guide or instructions?

Comment: I am relatively certain that these features were just released in Vault 1.10 and AzureRM provider 3.0. You may need to wait a bit before documentation or a proof of concept exists for this. You could always try it yourself and ask a question here when you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp has written a pretty comprehensive writeup on AzureAD with OIDC SSO here: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/auth-methods/oidc-auth-azure

I'm not sure it provides everything you are looking for, but its the most comprehensive walkthrough Ive found so far.